# Отсутствует заголовок CORS «Access-Control-Allow-Origin» при использовании fetch()?

Tags: javascript

Пишу одно расширение для браузера (на Tampermonkey). Отправляю запрос на сторонний сайт через fetch(), но это не работает. Ошибка в консоли:

```
Запрос из постороннего источника заблокирован: Политика одного источника запрещает чтение удаленного ресурса на https://pastebin.com/. (Причина: отсутствует заголовок CORS «Access-Control-Allow-Origin»). Код состояния: 200.
```

Можно ли обойти ошибку, при этом получив ответ от сервера?

Мой код:

```
fetch(url).then((data) => {
    alert(data)
})
```

Comment: Если уж вы используете Tampermonkey, значит используйте [GM_xmlhttpRequest](https://www.tampermonkey.net/documentation.php#GM_xmlhttpRequest) наверное?

Comment: @andreymal особой разницы нет, так и так можно отправить запрос, и там и там возвращается Promise.

Comment: @ΝNL993 есть очень существенная разница в работе с CORS

Comment: @dujor21 Нельзя, если сам сайт не разрешит подключения к другим сайтам. Если вам нужно получить какой-то скрипт с PasteBin, то можно с помощью `@require` подключить его, вот так: `// @require ССЫЛКА_НА_ВАШ_JS_СКРИПТ`. Просто убедитесь что это только сам скрипт и не более того (то есть никакой графической части сайта, только сам скрипт).

Comment: @andreymal хм... Я и не знал, спасибо за информацию :)